# I want to generate two variables random a and b in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to generate two random variables `a` and `b` using a shell script in Ubuntu. The variable `a` is a random integer between 0 to 10, while the variable b is a double/float number between 0 to 2, but the variable b should be two digits likes 0.1, 0.2...0.5 1.0, 2.0... Could you help me to write it? This is my current code:

```
min=0; 
max=10; 
ran=$RANDOM; 
for iter in {1..1..1}
    do
    a=($ran%$max+$min)
    b=
    echo $a, $b
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` to generate both numbers:

```
awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed); printf "%d : %.2f\n", int(rand()*10), rand()*2}'
```

To assign both numbers to shell variables:

```
read a b < <(awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed); printf "%d %.2f\n", int(rand()*10), rand()*2}')
echo "$a : $b"

5 : 1.51
```

**Testing:**

```
for i in {1..20}; do
   awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed); printf "%d : %.2f\n", int(rand()*10), rand()*2}'
done

3 : 0.63
4 : 0.73
9 : 1.31
8 : 0.32
2 : 1.35
4 : 0.72
7 : 0.71
7 : 1.91
3 : 1.90
0 : 1.39
5 : 1.95
2 : 1.38
7 : 0.71
5 : 0.38
1 : 0.47
3 : 1.96
2 : 0.80
9 : 0.51
6 : 0.73
0 : 1.58
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to assign them to a and b. Because i will use these variables latee

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The last thing I want to ask. Could we adjust the range [0.10] by min and max value. For example min=5 and max=15

Comment: Use: `int(rand()*(max-min))+min` to generate random number between `min` and `max`

Comment: It printed zero value. I used as `min=5 max=10 int(rand()*(max-min))+min`

Comment: `awk -v min=5 -v max=10 -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed); print int(rand()*(max-min))+min}'` works for me

Comment: Ok it worked. Sorry, I used min and max outside the line

Answer (score 3):

Only Bash

```
$ for i in $(seq 15); do
>     a=$(($RANDOM%21))
>     if [ $a -le 10 ]; then a='0.'${a}; else a=${a:0:1}.${a:1}; fi
>     echo $a
> done
2.0
1.4
0.9
0.3
0.0
1.6
1.7
1.9
1.6
1.8
0.9
0.3
1.2
1.1
0.6
$
```

I compute the module of a random number, `$RANDOM`, with respect to `21` — the result is an integer between `0` and `20`, included, and store the result in `a`.

If `a` is less then `10` I prepend  a zero and a dot, else I take the first character of `a`, insert a dot and eventually append the last character of `a`.

The manipulations of the two characters `a` are explained in the `bash (1)` man page:

> ```
>    ${parameter:offset}
>    ${parameter:offset:length}
>           Substring Expansion.  Expands to up to length
>           characters of the value of parameter starting at the
>           character specified by offset. [...]  If length is
>           omitted, expands to the substring of the value of
>           parameter starting at the character specified by
>           offset and extending to the end of the value.  length
>           and offset are arithmetic expressions (see ARITHMETIC
>           EVALUATION below).
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate value of b based on value of a

```
b=`echo "scale=1; $a/5" |bc| awk '{printf "%.1f", $0}'`
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Bash only (and some `expr` where needed). Up to 1.9 (from 0.0):

```
$ echo $(($RANDOM%2)).$(($RANDOM%10))
```

Up to 2.0 requires using (for example) `expr`:

```
$ r=3.0; while [ $(expr $r \<= 2.0) -eq 0 ] ; do r=$(($RANDOM%3)).$(($RANDOM%10)) ; done ; echo $r
1.4
```

Explained:

```
r=3.0                                 # value over threshold 2.0
while [ $(expr $r \<= 2.0) -eq 0 ]    # random until you get one <= 2.0
do 
    r=$(($RANDOM%3)).$(($RANDOM%10))  # random [012].[0-9]
done
echo $r                               # output it or not
```